# Не могу додуматься как модифицировать код python tkinter, что бы вызывать функции программное, а не через кнопки

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу реализовать Включение и выключение анимации по времени, в интернете нашел код только с кнопками на экране. Мне же нужно включать и выключать автоматически ставя `time.sleep()`. Помогите модифицировать данный код.

```
info = Image.open(file)
frames = info.n_frames  # gives total number of frames that gif contains
# creating list of PhotoImage objects for each frames
im = [tk.PhotoImage(file=file,format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(frames)]

count = 0
anim = None
def animation(count):
    global anim
    im2 = im[count]
    gif_label.configure(image=im2)
    count += 1
    if count == frames:
        count = 0
    anim = root.after(50,lambda :animation(count))

def stop_animation():
    root.after_cancel(anim)

gif_label = tk.Label(root,image="")
gif_label.pack()

start = tk.Button(root,text="start",command=lambda :animation(count))
start.pack()

stop = tk.Button(root,text="stop",command=stop_animation)
stop.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: план б. запустить threading который поспит включ поспит выключит. скока надо раз

Comment: Так и сделал, большое спсибо

Comment: Добавить еще одну функцию, периодически запускающуюся через root.after, и вызывающую animation и stop_animation